# Calculating age with scanner function doesnt work

Tags: java

first of all, I want to inform everyone that I just started to learn Java on the university. So please forgive me for any mistakes that I make as a newbie.

Basically what I want to achieve with this code is to calculate someone's age using the Scanner function. Someone enters their date of birth (in this format YYYY-MM-DD) and my code  calculates their age.

The code is not working, because I think the 3rd line: 
      **String dob = input.nextInt();** is wrong written and cannot be recognised by the code lines underneath it.

if I change that line into **String dob = "1988-11-29";** it works, but then my scanner function has no use.

Can someone help me with this?
Thanks in advance!

```
  Scanner input  = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter your DOB pls");
  String dob = input.nextInt();

  int yearDOB = Integer.parseInt(dob.substring(0, 4)); 
  int monthDOB = Integer.parseInt(dob.substring(5, 7)); 
  int dayDOB = Integer.parseInt(dob.substring(8, 10)); 

  SimpleDateFormat 
  dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy"); 
  Date date = new Date(); 
  int thisYear = Integer.parseInt(dateFormat.format(date)); 

  dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");
  date = new java.util.Date();
  int thisMonth = Integer.parseInt(dateFormat.format(date));

  dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
  date = new java.util.Date();
  int thisDay = Integer.parseInt(dateFormat.format(date));

  int age = thisYear-yearDOB;
  if(thisMonth < monthDOB){ age = age-1;
  } if(thisMonth == monthDOB && thisDay < dayDOB)
  { age = age-1;
  } 

  System.out.println("The age of user is : " + age);
```

Comment: Hint: `nextInt` reads a single integer number from the input stream. You want to read the whole line up to a newline.

Comment: All of `Scanner`'s methods can be found in the docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html (we're giving you hints rather than just telling you the answer because it'll be more helpful to you in the long run).

Comment: Also **never** parse dates manually, this is riddled with problems, use the `SimpleDateFormat` as you are using later in the code. To get parts of the date simply create a `Calendar` from the `Date` and use `get`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
String dob=s.next("[12][0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-3][0-9]");
int yearDOB = Integer.parseInt(dob.substring(0, 4)); 
int monthDOB = Integer.parseInt(dob.substring(5, 7)); 
int dayDOB = Integer.parseInt(dob.substring(8, 10));
Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
int thisYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int thisMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
int thisDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
// the rest is up to you
```

Comment: Love this code and it works for me. What is the reason you are using these specific numbers: [12][0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-3][0-9]. Isnt it easier to use [0-9]{4}-[0-9]{3}-{0-9}{2} ? and why should this be better than s.nextline()

Comment: The syntax is explained here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum  It’s pre-checking the format, first a one or two followed by three digits (i.e. a year) followed by a hyphen, two digits, another hyphen and a digit in the range 0-3 followed by a digit (a day in month). It does not exclude all wrong values but a lot.

Comment: Could be a challenge to improve that.

Answer (score 0):

when you write

```
String dob = input.nextInt()
```

you are trying to put an `int` into your `String`: `dob`.  `nextInt()` is the wrong method to use if you're trying to read your entire line of `1988-11-29`.

You might want to try [Scanner.nextLine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29), or some other method that returns a `String`

Comment: Thanks for the answer Sam I am! But I already found the solution thanks to Lee Meador's hint and iamnotmaynard's link. Thanks all!